# Meteor Js as frontend along with Koa Js as backend

Tags: node.js, meteor, koa

I am creating a Meteor Js app as frontend and i'm using Koa Js for backend. My purpose for Koa is to be able to monitor the pageviews on my frontend Meteor app.

Can you give me advice on how I am going to start?